# MySQL subquery to count user results in another table is sloooooooow

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a MySQL query which I'm running to return users and a count of their corresponding training results from an additional table, typically these are being displayed in the app front end 50 results at a time, however with this many results the query has become very slow.

Thing are infinitely better if I append the data using PHP after the MySQL query has run but this feels horrible and dirty and also prevents me from being able to sort on the result column. i.e. I would like to be able to sort users by the number of results they have. :)

Here's my current SQL query in all it's glory:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.email,
(SELECT COUNT(r.result_id)
    FROM programmes_results r
    WHERE ((r.client_id=users.client_id) AND (r.email=users.email))
) as results
FROM users
INNER JOIN users_groups ON users_groups.user_id=users.id
WHERE users.client_id='130' AND users_groups.group_id IN (5)
ORDER BY email asc
LIMIT 10
```

This takes in the region of 4 seconds to execute which is obviously totally pants. I'm sure there has to be an alternative way to return this extra data without incurring such a performance penalty but I'm at the bounds of my knowledge here.

Any pointers greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: did you make sure you had the needed indexes (run the query with `EXPLAIN` in front of it)?

Comment: yes, both client_id and email in users and programmes_results are indexed. I'll give EXPLAIN a shot. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT users.email, COUNT(r.result_id) as results
FROM users
INNER JOIN users_groups ON users_groups.user_id=users.id
INNER JOIN programmes_results r on ((r.client_id=users.client_id) AND (r.email=users.email))
WHERE users.client_id='130' AND users_groups.group_id IN (5)
group by users.email
ORDER BY users.email asc
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using CodeIgniter so it took me a while to recontrust that as an active record query but it works! Thanks ever so much, from ~4 secs down to ms! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is you don't have the right index on programmes_results. You need a single index that covers both client_id and email, having two separate indexes won't help very much, because it will only be able to use one of them, say, client_id and then have to scan all matching rows for ones that have the right email. Try:

```
CREATE INDEX id_email ON programmes_results (client_id, email)
```

and then run your query again.

Comment: How did I not realise that it was possible to create an index on two columns?! I'll try this in addition to the above, though restructuring my Subquery as a join seems to have done the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT u.email, 
       COUNT(r.result_id) AS results
FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_groups ug ON ug.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN programmes_results r ON r.client_id = u.client_id 
                                AND r.email = u.email
WHERE u.client_id = '130' AND ug.group_id IN (5)
GROUP BY u.email
ORDER BY u.email asc
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks Juergen, I think this is a duplicate of the above but no doubt typed at the same time. Thanks for the help, using the join seems to have fixed my problem. :)